# How do I pass selected values from a dropdown list to differents textboxes?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have a dropdown list and some textboxes (5). I would like to pass each selected item to respectively textbox1, textbox2... and so on.
How can I achieve this in either C# or jquery?

Thanks

Comment: more information needed. a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx).

Something like this:

Code Front:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="MyDropDown" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">
  ...
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
void MyDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var selectedValue = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
    textbox1.Text = selectedValue;
  else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text))
    textbox2.Text = selectedValue;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This snippet passes the same selected value to all the textboxes :( It´s supposed to pass a selected value to a define textbox. ie: selecteditem1 goes to textbox1 ...

Comment: You just need to check if textbox1 has any value in the text property, then assign the selecteditem to textbox2 etc. See the code change.

Comment: Thanks. That´s what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0

function setTextInTextField()
{
    document.getElementById('textfield' + i).value = document.getElementById('dropdownlist').value;
    i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do so:

```
    <asp:DropDownList id="MyDropDown" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    <asp:TextBox id="MyTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('select#"MyDropDown").change(function(){
     $('input#"MyTextBox").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Please take a look at the following url:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks, but your answer works for 1 textbox. What about with more than 1 textbox, where each selected item is passed to a different textbox. ie: selectedItem1 to textbox1, selectedItem2 to textbox2...